# Database data upgrade with versioning by environment

Tags: java, deployment, ansible, database-migration, flyway

I have a java app which I deploy on various plateforms (using ansible).

This app uses a database, which sometimes needs to get schema updates, which I perform and log/version with flyway (as a software dependency).

I now face the need to update data on all plateforms, but with different values depending on the plateforms. This is not a schema update, but is nonetheless data (list of other apps to which it connects) that forms the main structure of my app, and as such I want it to be versioned, in a similar way to what flyway does.

At first I was thinking I should input the different data in my ansible configuration, which seemed to make sense as it's ansible that knows about the various plateforms. And then I thought that this information would get passed to flyway somehow so that it performs the required updates.
However if that is handled using 'versioned migrations', I could end up with version conflicts because one environment requires an update and another doesn't (common versioning vs environment versioning).

There is a slight mention of this issue in the [flyway FAQ](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/faq#db-specific-sql), and one can set the `flyway.locations` property, or maybe I could use flyway placeholders that are set by ansible ?

Am I on the right track ? Or should I not use flyway altogether (is it meant to be used with DML, or should it be reserved for DDL) ?

Answer (score 0):

Flyway can be used for both schema and data updates. Although it's primary purpose is around versioning schema updates.

It sounds like you need a way to deploy some scripts only in certain environments. Flyway provides functionality that will support this workflow. However, you'll need to decide on the approach that works best for you.

Here are some ideas.

#### Use different locations

The simplest way I can think of is to have environment specific scripts in their own locations. You can also have a location for 'common' scripts.

When you deploy, you can specify the 'common' location, alongside the environment specific one. Something like:

`flyway migration -locations=common/sql, test/sql`
`flyway migration -locations=common/sql, production/sql`

And so on.

#### `shouldExecute` script config & placeholders

Another way is to use the Flyway Teams feature [`shouldExecute`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/scriptconfigfiles). This let's you define a boolean expression to determine if a script should be run. You can inject a value from a [placeholder](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/placeholder). There is a [blog post](https://flywaydb.org/blog/shouldexecute) that explains more about it.

#### Use the `cherryPick` configuration option

Another Teams Edition feature is [`cherryPick`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/cherryPick), which allows you to specify exactly which scripts to deploy. So you might have a configuration file per environment with a `cherryPick` config that specifies the exact scripts to run. This one might be unwieldy since you need to explicitly list every script, but it does give you complete control.